# Matlab: contourf, repeated data points: median instead of average

Tags: matlab, contourf

I use `contourf` function for plotting a 2D filled contour.

I get warning that some of the data points for Z are repeated and average values will be used in that case.

Can I somehow force Matlab to use the median values instead?

Thank you.

File: [MyData.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxLFPpDUfv9PVHhZb0MyVkJ4WDg)

Comment: Can you show us an example of the matrix?

Comment: How about searching for repeated values and taking the median before calling `contourf`?

Comment: @RPM, I tried that but I could not do it. To look up all repeated Z values for a given (X,Y) and find a median and form another matrix to be used for contourf.

Comment: @Ander Biguri, please check the file link.